# Removing scales in a picture

Tags: java, image, opencv

[image: number image]

I have attached the picture. On the picture there are these numbers 2.06x and the picture also has white scales.

I like to know, using java how can I remove the white scales an have the numbers only left in a picture with no white scales? Even if the background is removed, it would be fine.

I don't mind an opencv java suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those light stripes in the background are your concern, this might help you (otherwise I misunderstood your question). It takes color samples throughout the image (always skipping 8 pixels for performance, you can increase/decrease this).
If figures out the lightest and darkest color and replaces every pixel with the closer of those two colors.

This is not an opencv solution, but i hope it still works for you.
(Of course you still need to insert the correct paths into the new File() expressions.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File imageFile = new File();
    File outputFile = new File();
    
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
    removeScales(image, outputFile);
}

private static void removeScales(BufferedImage image, File imageFile) throws IOException {
    Color lightest = Color.BLACK;
    Color darkest = Color.WHITE;

    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x += 8) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y += 8) {
            Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));

            if (isDarker(color, darkest)) darkest = color;
            if (isLighter(color, lightest)) lightest = color;
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));

            if (differenceSquared(color, lightest) < differenceSquared(color, darkest)) {
                image.setRGB(x, y, lightest.getRGB());
            } else {
                image.setRGB(x, y, darkest.getRGB());
            }
        }
    }
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", imageFile);
}

private static boolean isLighter(Color color, Color lightest) {
    return (
            (color.getRed() + color.getGreen() + color.getBlue())
                    > (lightest.getRed() + lightest.getGreen() + lightest.getBlue())
    );
}

private static boolean isDarker(Color color, Color darkest) {
    return (
            (color.getRed() + color.getGreen() + color.getBlue())
                    < (darkest.getRed() + darkest.getGreen() + darkest.getBlue())
    );
}

private static double differenceSquared(Color a, Color b) {
    return Math.pow(a.getRed() - b.getRed(), 2)
            + Math.pow(a.getGreen() - b.getGreen(), 2)
            + Math.pow(a.getBlue() - b.getBlue(), 2);
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: So a median filter?

Comment: As far as I understand it, it's not a median filter. Note that the output image will only have two colors. But I might very well be wrong!